# VBA, Sorting based on custom list

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to sort my records based on Col A values, there are 5 different values and many rows (in a table). Also I have the custom list created in excels built in sort feature.

I am getting an error `Sort method of range class failed` on

```
oRangeSort.Sort Key1:=oRangeKey, Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
    OrderCustom:=Application.CustomListCount + 1, MatchCase:=False, _
    Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
```

Here is my code:

```
Sub Sort()



Dim oWorksheet As Worksheet
Set oWorksheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("database")
Dim oRangeSort As Range
Dim oRangeKey As Range

' one range that includes all colums do sort
Set oRangeSort = oWorksheet.Range("A2:FR20000")
' start of column with keys to sort
Set oRangeKey = oWorksheet.Range("A2")

' custom sort order
Dim sCustomList(1 To 5) As String
sCustomList(1) = "sort1"
sCustomList(2) = "sort2"
sCustomList(3) = "sort3"
sCustomList(4) = "sort4"
sCustomList(5) = "sort5"

Application.AddCustomList ListArray:=sCustomList


oWorksheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
oRangeSort.Sort Key1:=oRangeKey, Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
    OrderCustom:=Application.CustomListCount + 1, MatchCase:=False, _
    Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

' clean up
ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
Application.DeleteCustomList Application.CustomListCount
Set oWorksheet = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: You should know if you have a header or not. Never let Excel xlGuess in a programmed sort.

Comment: @Jeeped, do you know the syntax for knowing there is a header? I always have headers.

Comment: `Header:=xlYes` not `Header:=xlGuess`.

Comment: @Jeeped, still getting same error,any other ideas?

Comment: That was not actually intended as an answer, only a comment to improve your code toward a 'best practices' ideal. See below for legitimate response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a VBA sort as opposed to rewriting the recorded sort code.

```
Sub custom_sort()
    Dim vCustom_Sort As Variant, rr As Long

    vCustom_Sort = Array("sort1", "sort2", "sort3", "sort4", "sort5")
    Application.AddCustomList ListArray:=vCustom_Sort

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("database")
        .Sort.SortFields.Clear
        rr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        With .Range("A2:FR" & rr)
            .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(1), Order1:=xlAscending, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, _
                        Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes, MatchCase:=False, _
                        OrderCustom:=Application.CustomListCount + 1

        End With
        .Sort.SortFields.Clear
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks jeeped, I am having an issue, the first row (a2) of data (a1 is headers) is staying put and everything else is sorting. Do  you know why this is?